# UIScrollView doen't scroll when is into a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to use a UIScrollView as the content view into a PageViewController, I've configured the Page controller as it is on the sample project of xcode.

The problem is that the content has a Scroll view but it just doesn't scroll at all, I have seted the Content size and the properties for the scroll view.. I guess it is right configured.

```
- (UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (_scrollView == NULL) {
        _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
        _scrollView.backgroundColor      = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _scrollView.scrollEnabled        = TRUE;
        _scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = TRUE;
    }
    return _scrollView;
}
```

Then, I'd attached the gestures of my view to be the UIPageViewController gestures array, this was preventing a navigation bar to perform well, so I made a validation on:

```
gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:
```

And it is ok now.

I don't know how to fix this issue :S

Comment: Did you find a solution? Can you share it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 [scrollmngmt setScrollEnabled:YES];
 [scrollmngmt setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1200)];



 [self setScrollmngmt:nil];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks I made the changes and realized that my View has the same size as the scroll view. I'll fix this and see if that was the problem.

Comment: It doesn't work, is it possible that the PageView is preventing the right behavior of the scroll view's gestures?